# Single POJO for different REST operations with validation

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I'm designing a REST service and am running into the issue that for a given object, I have multiple "states".

- The object as it arrives on the initial POST operation.
- The Object I store in our DB
- The Object I return on a GET
- The Object I expect on a PATCH

e.g.

```
class MyObject {

// Unwanted on POST
// Required on PATCH
// Included on GET
@JsonProperty("id")
private UUID id;

// Everywhere
@NonNull
@JsonProperty("name")
private String name;

// Field I need for internal processing but don't want included in REST.
private AuditTrail stuff;

@JsonCreator
@Builder
public MyObject(...) { ... }
}


...


@Get
public ResponseEntity myFunction(HttpServletRequest request,
                                 @RequestBody @Valid MyObject requestBody) {
...
}
```

The issue I am running into is that on POST, when the id is omitted, the deserialization fails.  I got around it using @JsonIgnoreProperties(), but now on PATCH, where I do want the id present, things work if it is omitted.

Another alternative we toyed with was to have two objects.  The first one with the common fields for POST and the other extending from it with the rest, but it feel messy, especially as we deal with objects more complex than the simple example.

It's not actually a problem since I validate and sanitize inputs anyway, but I was wondering if there is a clean way in Jackson to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning a rest service then you don't need the id in the body anyway. The id will come from the url as a pathvariable:

`POST myobjects`

`GET myobjects/{id}`

`PATCH myobjects/{id}`

Comment: Alright, maybe I picked the wrong field for my gutted example.  Let's say you have a lastUpdated field.  that is not required on POST since it's not user controlled, but you do have it on GET.
And you do need to return the ID in the object at some point or the user has no way of knowing it :)

Comment: `@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)`